# REST api to allow multiple users edit the same form at the same time

Tags: rest

I'm looking to make something similar to google docs where everyone can update the form (with multiple input fields) at the same time using REST api, the form data will be stored in database, is it possible?

I can have the form to send an update request whenever user make a change, but I still can't quite figure out what the logic to retrieve data/update form field content and resolve conflict when users are editing the same field.

Comment: This is possible through sockets, you can explore socket.io to send realtime events and notifications to other users connected to the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) for realtime communication as well as pushing the updates to other users belonging to the similar group (may be call it as users of a same form). SignalR will provide all the underline infrastructure in place.